# Passport req.session.passport always gives undefined on other api calls

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Using passport session is showing undefined for other api calls. For the callback api it is is showing the value

Below is my code. In authenticationMiddleWare the req.session.passport is undefined. But the value is printing inside the /auth call. So inside the auth call i am setting the session and consoling it in post /api call. But that time the session is not shows user details. I am getting only the below result

```
cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2022-05-13T04:53:57.715Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    ephimeral: true
  }
```

Below is my code. Please help me to solve the issue

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const loadRouter = require("./routes/index");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const fs = require("fs");
var session = require("express-session");
 var passport = require("passport");
 var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
 var SamlStrategy = require("passport-saml").Strategy;

 app.use(
    session({
      secret: "$$$$",
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        ephimeral: true,
      },
    })
  );
   passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log(user)
    done(null, user);
  });
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "callback_url");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "deny");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache, no-store");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser("$$$$"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

passport.use(
   new SamlStrategy(
     {
       callbackUrl:"callbackUrl",
       entryPoint: "entryPoint",
       issuer: 'issuer',
       cert: "cert",
       identifierFormat: 'identifierFormat',
       decryptionPvk: "decryptionPvk",
       protocol: "https://",
       privateCert: "privateCert"
  
     },
     function (profile, done) {
       var user_info = {
         name_id: profile.nameID,
         email: profile.EMAIL,
         manager: profile.Manager,
         employee_type: profile.EmployeeType,
       };
       return done(null, user_info);
     }
   )
 );



app.post(
  "/auth",
  passport.authenticate("saml", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    req.session.user =req.session.passport.user ;
    res.redirect("/home");
  }
);

 paths_to_be_excluded = [
  "/login",
  "/",
];

var authenticationMiddleWare = function (req, res, next) {
  if (
    paths_to_be_excluded.indexOf(req.path) <= 0 ||
    typeof req.session.passport !== "undefined"
  ) {
       next();
    } else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
};

app.get("/login", function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("saml", {
      failureRedirect: "/",
      failureFlash: true,
    })(req, res, next);
  });
    

app.use(authenticationMiddleWare);


 app.post("/api", function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.session)
}); 

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.passport) {
    if (req.session.passport.user.sso_role) {
      res.cookie("user_id", req.session.passport.user.id, {
        maxAge: 90000,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
      });
    } else {
      res.cookie("user_id", "FORBIDDEN", {
        maxAge: 90000,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.cookie("user_id", "FORBIDDEN", {
      maxAge: 90000,
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
  }
  next();
});

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
    app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build/index.html")));


const PORT =  9001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App Running On Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

An api call from front end

```
let url = getURL() + "/api";
            fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                credentials: "same-origin",
                body: JSON.stringify({"id": id, "code": code}),
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } 
            })
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the way you call the api (in your front-end)

Comment: I add the api call in the question.

Comment: can you try this method they mentioned ? 

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/244#issuecomment-274571839

You may have to pass credentials: "same-origin" , while using fetch.

Comment: even i tried same-origin also. But still not working

Comment: Why oh why would you try and handle CORS manually? The industry standard [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware already covers everything you need

Comment: Are the front and back ends on different domains (ie different hostnames and / or ports)?

Comment: it is same port reading the react build file from node server

Comment: @user1187 are you having this issue also on your productive environment? the flag `secure: true` only sends the cookie if you are using https.

Comment: yes in prod only i am facing this issue it is secure and using https

Comment: Have you tried just using req.user instead of req.session.passport?

Comment: I understood that my cookie is not setting. But in code what am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved it. We need to use "cookie-session" instead of "express-session". So I just changed

```
var session = require("cookie-session");
```